# Rotating rectangle on canvas android

Tags: android, canvas, rectangles

I created an activity which settings another activity as view, in this activity I created Canvas (onDraw) and inside a rectangle, now I want to rotate it, I tried `canvas.rotate()` but it seems nothing happens. here is my code:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
private Rect rec1;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)    getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int y = metrics.heightPixels;
    int x = metrics.widthPixels;
    rec1 = new Rect(x / 2 - 25, 0, x / 2 + 25, y);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(rec1, paint);
    for (int j = 1; j <= 200; j++) {
        canvas.rotate(5);
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what's the problem? I also checked if the problem is in `for` so I deleted it and added a line `canvas.rotate(45)` , yet nothing.

Here's the MainActivity if needed

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);

      }
 }
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anim/rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

---

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#f90"
    android:id="@+id/rect"/>
```

---

```
View rect = findViewById(R.id.rect);
Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
rect.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: The part you edited, the View xml file, where should I put it?

Comment: Well, most apps will use a [layout xml](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts.htm).

Comment: Well, the whole idea of going with view animations was that you don't have to mess with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rotate before you draw:

```
canvas.rotate(45);
canvas.drawRect(rec1, paint);
```

Comment: and can't I rotate after? I mean, I want to create a rectangle, see it, and then rotate it..

Comment: Emm.. I want it to rotate fast and if you touch it something will happen, if  I will animate it like a spin, the command "rec1.contains(x,y)" will still work?

Comment: Have you considered using [animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)?

Comment: do you know how to make a spin animation? and how can I loop it forever, I want it to spin permanently